# Nilpotents in a domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

What are the nilpotent elements in a domain? Doesn't it depend on what ring it is? Example, in $\mathbb{R}$ it is 0 but in $\mathbb{Z}_8$ it is $2$ because $(2)^3 = 8 = 0$.

Comment: I'd say that the ring $\Bbb Z_8$ wasn't a **domain**....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$0$ is the only nilpotent in any domain since by definition a domain has no $0$ divisors.